# For inner product spaces, do we have $||\vec{u}-\vec{v}|| \leq ||\vec{u}||+||\vec{v}||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Let $V$ be an inner product space.  Then for all $\vec{u},\vec{v} \in V$ we have $$||\vec{u}-\vec{v}|| \leq ||\vec{u}||+||\vec{v}||.$$

I know that the converse to the equation is true such that $||\vec{u}+\vec{v}||$ is less than or equal to $||\vec{u}||+||\vec{v}||$.  Is this also true?

Comment: Why not just post the question here? By only giving a link to the question, you're essentially asking the community to complete a chore before helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the triangle inequality $\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$.  What happens if you do $y\leftarrow -y$?

Answer (score 0):

It's true not only in inner-product spaces but also in normed vector spaces in general (in fact, it is sufficient that $\|\cdot\|$ is merely a seminorm on $V$). As mentioned by @ncmathsadist, use the triangle inequality and absolute homogeneity of the norm: $\|\lambda\mathbf v\|=|\lambda|\|\mathbf v\|$ for any $\mathbf v\in V$ and any $\lambda$ in the underlying field (in particular, $\lambda=-1$, if we're talking about real or complex vector spaces).